# Edit Data in Parent from Child

Tags: reactjs

Apparently I'm not doing this right, but I'm trying to mutate a map in the parent component from a child component in React 18.2. The parent contains a modal which opens a form. The user then inputs their mutate option (delete/add) and subsequent data from there. I've been going through other questions trying to find an answer for why it's not working as intended, but I can't seem to find much info. Would appreciate any help. This is what I currently have:

Parent.Js

```
const ParentComponent = ({show, onCloseModalButton}) => {
    const resorts = new Map()
    resorts.set("Keystone", [39.6069742, -105.97011])
    resorts.set("Breckenridge", [39.4808, -106.0676])
    resorts.set("Vail", [39.6061, -106.3550])
    resorts.set("Crested Butte", [38.8991, -106.9658])
    resorts.set("Winter Park", [39.8841, -105.7627])
    resorts.set("Copper Mountain", [39.5022, -106.1497])

    const [formOption, setFormOption] = React.useState("")
    
    const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState({
        resortName: "",
        longitude: Number,
        latitude: Number,
    })

    const handleOptionChange = e => {
        setFormOption(e.target.value)
    }

    const handleFormDataChange = e => {
        setFormData({
            ...formData,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        })
    }

    const submitForm = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (formOption === "Add") {
            resorts.set(formData.resortName, [formData.latitude, formData.longitude])
        }
        if (formOption === "Delete") {
            resorts.delete(formData.resortName)
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Modal show={show} onCloseModalButton={onCloseModalButton} resorts={resorts} submitForm={submitForm} handleOptionChange={handleOptionChange} handleFormChange={handleFormDataChange} option={formOption} form={formData} />
        </div>
    )
}
export default ParentComponent;
```

Modal.js

```
const Modal = ({show, onCloseModalButton, resorts, submitForm, handleOptionChange, handleFormChange, option, form}) => {
    
    if (!show) {
        return null
    }

    return ReactDOM.createPortal (
       <div className='modal-bg'>
            <div className='modal'>
                <form onSubmit={submitForm}>
                    <label>Modify: 
                        <select 
                        name="option"
                        value={option}
                        onChange={handleOptionChange}
                        >
                            <option value="" disabled={true}>-- Choose an Option --</option>
                            <option value="Add">Add</option>
                            <option value="Delete">Delete</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                    {option === "" ? null :
                        option === "Add" ?
                            <div>
                                <label>Resort Name 
                                    <input 
                                    type="text" 
                                    name="resortName"
                                    value={form.resortName}
                                    onChange={handleFormChange}
                                    />
                                </label>
                                <br></br>
                                <label>Longitude
                                    <input 
                                    type="number" 
                                    name="longitude"
                                    value={form.longitude}
                                    onChange={handleFormChange}
                                    />
                                </label>
                                <br></br>
                                <label>Latitude
                                    <input 
                                    type="number" 
                                    name="latitude"
                                    value={form.latitude}
                                    onChange={handleFormChange}
                                    />
                                </label>
                                <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
                            </div> :
                            <div>
                                <label>Delete
                                    <select 
                                    name="delete"
                                    value={form.resortName}
                                    onChange={handleFormChange}
                                    >   
                                        {[...resorts.keys()].map((item)=> {
                                            return <option key={item} value={item}>{item}</option>
                                        })}
                                    </select>
                                </label>
                                <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
                            </div>
                    }
                </form>
                <button onClick={onCloseModalButton}>Close Modal</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        , document.body
    )
}
export default Modal;
```

Comment: You need to use React state for this.  Your Map object will get recreated on every render of the parent.

Comment: Consider saving the default values for your Map somewhere in another file, and import/address it from there. Also, read about previous state to avoid overwriting. For example, make `setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })` as `setFormData(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }))`. It's a good first step.

Comment: @LindaPaiste Thanks, that makes sense. assuming I write `const [resorts, setResorts] = React.useState({})`, I'm just a little confused on how would i use the `setResorts` function

Comment: @Rusurano Just to clarify, but would writing the resorts map in App.js, including a resorts prop to ParentComponent to pass the resorts map to, adding state to the resorts map in ParentComponent, and then making an "import" function that calls a setResorts state function work?

Comment: @Grant I would suggest putting Resorts themselves in a state in App.js, then assign the value of a context to `resorts` and `setResorts`, putting this context's provider inside App.js, and consume the context in your parent component. This way, you will modify the state of Resorts without redundant logic.

Comment: @Rusurano thanks! that sounds like it should work. will read up on how context works and how to implement it